# ORACLE - What is the Problem with date in External Table?

Tags: oracle, external-tables

I'm trying to load data from a CSV file. The date value in the file is correct.
And in the table, some values are incorrect.

[image]

```
 CREATE TABLE "TABLE" 
   (  "TIMESTAMP" VARCHAR2(4000)
   ) 
   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
    ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
      DEFAULT DIRECTORY "UPLOAD"
      ACCESS PARAMETERS
      ( records delimited by newline
         CHARACTERSET CL8MSWIN1251
         NODISCARDFILE
         NOLOGFILE
         NOBADFILE
         skip 1
         fields terminated BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
                                      )
      LOCATION
       ( "UPLOAD":'table.csv'
       )
    )
   REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

What could be the mistake?

Comment: Is the displayed data from the CSV file or output from the table? Whatever it is please post the other one (preferably for the matching rows).

Comment: It is a bad idea to store timestamp values as `VARCHAR2` - use `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`. Also using reserved word `TIMESTAMP` as column name is a poor choice.

Comment: Looks like you have Excel-based data there; can you edit your question to include some sample data from your file `table.csv` ?